# Left Join with Yii CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT messages.id, 
       messages.sender_id, 
       messages.subject, 
       messages.body, 
       messages.created_at, 
       user.username AS username  
FROM messages  LEFT JOIN user ON user.iduser=messages.sender_id
```

I tried to change the query to the CDbCriteria model's as follows:

```
$criteria   = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = "messages.id, messages.sender_id, messages.subject, messages.body, messages.created_at, user.username AS username";
$criteria->alias  = "messages";
$criteria->join   = "LEFT JOIN user ON user.iduser=messages.sender_id";
$messagesAdapter = Message::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But, when I execute the query, appear error as follows:

> Property "Message.username" is not defined.

What is an error in the query ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `relation name` to print the **username** or **user attributes**, ie. user.*.

For that you should have relation in you Message model for User model. 
Something like..

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(            
        ......
        ......

        'userRel' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'isuser'),
        ......
    );
}
```

Now, you can print username using this relation name `userRel`

```
//check this
print_r($messagesAdapter[0]->userRel);

//May be you can get username with below statement as you are using left join
echo $messagesAdapter[0]->userRel[0]->username;
```